# php - How to restart a script/page if it fails or times out?

Tags: php

Is there a way of restarting a php script/page (or re-executing a function/loop within that script) if it dies or reaches a maximum script execution time out?

I would like to do this on the server level somehow if possible (without using cron), but I wouldn't mind a simple browser ajax/javascript based solution too.

At the moment I am forced to press F5 to refresh the browser if it fails..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it pure HTML, and refresh every 30 seconds, add this in the `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

Comment: Thanks, but, as above, I need the page to refresh if the script has timed out during a function, or failed for some reason.. not after an interval.

Comment: Then PHP/Apache is the wrong stack I guess : (( - or you could just end your script with some custom HTML tag [e.g. `<div id="done">`], and check via js [with a script in the `<head>` section] if it exists after let's say 10 sec: if not, you reload the page.

Comment: that's actually not a bad solution at all, but it's a long script (takes a few hours), so it would either HAVE to refresh a few times or the interval would be very long... Is there any way of getting js to simply check if a php error has appeared on the page perhaps? Feel free to reply in a separate answer so I can vote it up or whatnot. Thanks.